# Multiplying 2 numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays, the shape of the first array `A` is `(36,)` and the second one `B` is `(36, 4)`. The idea is to multiply corresponding elements like `A[0] * B[0]` in the way that each of 4 elements of B gets multiplied with corresponding element of A.

Comment: What is your question? Have you read the NumPy docs?

Comment: According to broadcasting rules, you have to explicitly add any trailing dimensions, thus the (36,) => (36,1).  `numpy` can handle the rest.  New leading dimensions are automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a new axis to `A` in order to enable broadcasting.

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(36,4))
B = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(36,))

A * B.reshape(-1, 1)
```