# Multiply multidimensional numpy array by 1-D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a multidimensional array and a set of scale factors that I want to apply along the first axis:

```
>>> data.shape, scale_factors.shape
((22, 20, 2048, 2048), (22,))
>>> data * scale_factors
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (22,20,2048,2048) (22,)
```

I can do this with apply_along_axis, but is there a vectorized way to do this? I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59887136/multiplying-2-numpy-arrays), but the solution is specific to a 1-D * 2-D operation. The "data" ndarray will not always be the same shape, and won't even always have the same number of dimensions. But the length of the 1-D scale_factors will always be the same as axis 0 of data.

Comment: `expand_dims` takes a tuple, so you can add a number of trailing dimensions with something like: `np.expand_dims(np.arange(5),tuple(range(1,4)))`.  Under the covers, `expand_dims` constructs a `shape` and does a `reshape`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try reshape the `data` into 2D, then broadcast `scale_factor` to 2D, and reshape back:

```
(data.reshape(data.shape[0], -1) * scale_factors[:,None]).reshape(data.shape)
```

Or, you can swap the `0`-th axis to the last so you can [broadcast](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules):

```
(data.swapaxes(0,-1) * scale_factors).swapaxes(0,-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
data * scale_factors.reshape([-1]+[1]*(len(data.shape)-1))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data * scale_factors[:,None,None,None]
```

Comment: *The "data" ndarray will not always be the same shape, and won't even always have the same number of dimensions.*